# I can't set input value when match with user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three input box but the last two are disable for input . When user input in `first input` , I matching with json data `com` and if there match exist the last two input will automatically set value from matched json.

For now, my code is not working for all name input !

> input -> acid -> not working
>
> input -> gosd -> working

```js
var com = [
{id:1,name:"Acid",phone:4455,address:'Main'},
{id:2,name:"Gosd",phone:555,address:'Lab'}
];


$('[name="com-name"]').on("keyup",function () {
  com.filter(v => {
    if(v.name.toLowerCase() == $(this).val().toLowerCase() ) {
        $('[name="com-pho"]').val(v.phone);
        $('[name="com-add"]').val(v.address);
        return false;
    }
    $('[name="com-pho"]').val('');
    $('[name="com-add"]').val('');
  })
});
```

```css
input:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="com-name"><br>
<input type="text" name="com-pho"><br>
<input type="text" name="com-add">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the code which empty the values from textboxes and move it to the beginning

```js
var com = [
{id:1,name:"Acid",phone:4455,address:'Main'},
{id:2,name:"Gosd",phone:555,address:'Lab'}
];


$('[name="com-name"]').on("keyup",function () {
   $('[name="com-pho"]').val('');
   $('[name="com-add"]').val('');
  com.filter(v => {
    if(v.name.toLowerCase() == $(this).val().toLowerCase() ) {
        $('[name="com-pho"]').val(v.phone);
        $('[name="com-add"]').val(v.address);
        return false;
    }
    
  })
});
```

```css
input:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="com-name"><br>
<input type="text" name="com-pho"><br>
<input type="text" name="com-add">
```